# Square bracket Syntax Above Property Declaration

Tags: c#, .net

I keep seeing the following syntax when looking at C# code (using .NET 4.0 framework):

```
    [XmlIgnore, Bindable(false)]
    public virtual FieldBase Field {get;set;}
```

What is the purpose of the square brackets above the property header?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

These are [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), they can be applied to elements of your code-base and in doing so applies metadata to that thing - like descriptive declarations. These things can have multiple attributes. There are a bunch of 'built-in' attributes exposes by the .NET framework, you can however define your own.

Types that are attributes are actually defined with a fully qualified name of `SuchAThingAttribute`, whereas in being applied you need only specify the name minus `Attribute` which becomes `SuchAThing`. And they must derive from [`System.Attribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.aspx) (at least to be compliant).

An attribute can have 'settings', that is, you can specify (when writing your own) which types of elements the attribute is applicable to, and whether an element can have more than one of this type of attribute or not, and so on.

The metadata of the attribute can later be got at using [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and `GetCustomAttribute`-like methods. Links [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kff8s254.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130866.aspx) show examples of doing so.

Answer (score 8):

These are attributes.
Please take a look at [Attributes (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 6):

These are attributes assigned to the variable. A classic use case is for enforcing model properties that they are applied to.

When used in conjunction with Code First principles, the validation rules specified in these attributes in a model are enforced before the application saves changes in the database and avoids bad data going into your database.

```
public class Person
{
    //We cannot have a digit as part of a Person's name, unless ofcourse
    //you are Elon Musks child
    [RegularExpression(@"[^0-9]*")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking at is an [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287992%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  The square bracket is the syntax required to specifiy the application of an attribute to a given member, in this case a property accessor, but attributes can also be applied to classes etc.